# Adding a text input dialogue box in psychopy using python?

Tags: python, psychopy

I am using psychopy and python to program a simple psychology experiment.  Basically, a foreign word appears on the screen for 8 seconds, followed by 5 seconds of a translation of that word.  During the 8 second exposure to the foreign word, participants are instructed to type in a guess as to what the translation might be.  When they start typing, their text appears underneath the foreign word that is being displayed on the screen.

Here is my question; how can include a dialogue, input text box in my experiment underneath the foreign word where they type and their letters appear, rather than just appearing beneath the word with no border or boundary?

Comment: Just draw a rectangle (e.g. a `ShapeStim` in Coder or a `polygon component` in Builder) at the required location?

Answer (score 1):

I made something similar to what you are describing a while back. Perhaps this will help. You first have some TextStim, and some predefined keys:

```
instruction = psychopy.visual.TextStim(myWindow,color="white")
quitKeys = ['escape', 'esc']
ansKeys = ['space', 'return']
keyboardKeys = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
answer = ''
```

And then you have a loop, where inside of it you have something like this
(I'm guessing you would also have something relating to the foreign word you are showing)

```
#Loop Starts Here>
instruction.setText(u':{0}'.format(answer))
instruction.draw()

myWindow.flip()
# get some keys.
for letter in (keyboardKeys):
    if psychopy.event.getKeys([letter]):
        answer += letter

if psychopy.event.getKeys(['backspace']):
    answer = answer[:-1]

if psychopy.event.getKeys([quitKeys[0]]):
    psychopy.core.quit()

if psychopy.event.getKeys([ansKeys[1]]):  # enter is pressed
    # and they have given their answer, So some code to check their answer
```

Hope this helps